# CompletableFuture usability and unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I'm learning about java 8 `CompletableFuture` and ended up with this.

Fist of all, what do you think about this lines of code? I need to send request to different services in parallel and then wait for all of them to response and continue working.

```
//service A
CompletableFuture<ServiceAResponse> serviceAFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
    () -> this.ServiceA.retrieve(serviceARequest), serviceAExecutorService
);

//service B
CompletableFuture<ServiceBResponse> serviceBFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
    () -> this.ServiceB.retrieve(serviceBRequest), serviceBExecutorService
);

CompletableFuture.allOf(serviceAFuture, serviceBFuture).join();
ServiceAResponse responseA = serviceAFuture.join();
ServiceBResponse responseB = serviceBFuture.join();
```

And even the code is doing what I want, I'm having problems testing the class where that code is. I tried using Mockito and do something like:

```
doAnswer(invocation -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(this.serviceAResponse))
    .when(this.serviceAExecutorService)
    .execute(any());
```

Where executor services and services responses are mocking but the test never ends and the thread keeps waiting for something in this line

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(serviceAFuture, serviceBFuture).join();
```

Any hint on what I'm missing here? Thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If I were you, I would simply mock the services A and B and your executors, then inject them thanks to the annotation [`@InjectMocks`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) as they are fields of your class.

If you want mock the method `execute` of your `Executor`, you should rather proceed as next to simply call the method `run` of the provided `Runnable`:

```
doAnswer(
    (InvocationOnMock invocation) -> {
        ((Runnable) invocation.getArguments()[0]).run();
        return null;
    }
).when(serviceAExecutorService).execute(any(Runnable.class));
```

So basically your test would be something like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CompletableFutureServiceTest {

    // The mock of my service A
    @Mock
    private ServiceA ServiceA;
    // The mock of my service B
    @Mock
    private ServiceB ServiceB;
    // The mock of your executor for the service A
    @Mock
    private Executor serviceAExecutorService;
    // The mock of your executor for the service B
    @Mock
    private Executor serviceBExecutorService;
    // My class in which I want to inject the mocks
    @InjectMocks
    private CompletableFutureService service;

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        // Mock the method execute to call the run method of the provided Runnable
        doAnswer(
            (InvocationOnMock invocation) -> {
                ((Runnable) invocation.getArguments()[0]).run();
                return null;
            }
        ).when(serviceAExecutorService).execute(any(Runnable.class));
        doAnswer(
            (InvocationOnMock invocation) -> {
                ((Runnable) invocation.getArguments()[0]).run();
                return null;
            }
        ).when(serviceBExecutorService).execute(any(Runnable.class));

        ServiceAResponse serviceAResponse = ... // The answer to return by service A
        // Make the mock of my service A return my answer
        when(ServiceA.retrieve(any(ServiceARequest.class))).thenReturn(
            serviceAResponse
        );
        ServiceBResponse serviceBResponse = ... // The answer to return by service B
        // Make the mock of my service B return my answer
        when(ServiceB.retrieve(any(ServiceBRequest.class))).thenReturn(
            serviceBResponse
        );

        // Execute my method
        ServiceResponse response = service.someMethod(
            new ServiceARequest(), new ServiceBRequest()
        );

        // Test the result assuming that both responses are wrapped into a POJO
        Assert.assertEquals(serviceAResponse, response.getServiceAResponse());
        Assert.assertEquals(serviceBResponse, response.getServiceBResponse());
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing this I get NPE because I have to mock my ExecutorService (I'm using a custom one) but if I use a moked one, the test never ends. 

Of course if I use the default executor service, without sending mine to CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(), it works like a charm .

Comment: YES! thank you! that's what I have to do always I want to mock the ExecutionService.execute() method? It is exactly what I was trying to do but in a way it works.

Answer (score 11):

```
  @Mock
  private AsyncExecuter asyncExecuter;
  @Mock
  private CompletableFuture<XyzSample> xyzSampleResponse;
  @Mock
  private CompletableFuture<Map<String, String>> abcSampleResponse;

 @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

    abcSampleResponse = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(TestUtil.readJsonResource(
        "misc_mapper_response.json", new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
        }));

    xyzSampleResponse = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(TestUtil.readJsonResource(
        "gp_facade_response.json", new TypeReference<XyzSample>() {
        }));

  }

   @Test
  public void testAbcMethod() {

    Mockito.doReturn(abcSampleResponse).when(asyncExecuter)
        .callPgEndpoint(TestConstants.TEST_CUSTOMER_ID);

    Mockito.doReturn(xyzSampleResponse).when(asyncExecuter)
        .getUserPreference(TestConstants.TEST_CUSTOMER_ID);


    final ActualResponse actualResponse = globalPositionService
        .getGlobalPosition(TestConstants.TEST_CUSTOMER_ID);

    assertNotNull(actualResponse);
}

=====Service
public ActualResponse getGlobalPosition(final String customerId) {

    final CompletableFuture<Map<String, String>> abcSampleResponse = asyncExecuter
        .getProductTypeInfo();
    final CompletableFuture<XyzSample> xyzSampleResponse = asyncExecuter
        .getUserPreference(customerId);

    try {
      return new ResponseDecorator(pgResponse.get(), userPreferenceResponse.get(),
          productTypeInfo.get()).decorate();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      log.error("Error Occurred while building the response", e);
    }
    return null;
  }

@Component
public class AsyncExecuter {
  public CompletableFuture<XyzSample> callPgEndpoint(final String customerId) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(xxx);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved this for JUnit5 and Mockito

```
@Spy ThreadPoolTaskExecutor spyTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
```

And

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    openMocks(this);
    spyTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    spyTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    spyTaskExecutor.initialize();
}
```